# Can YAML entries be used a subsets of entries in same file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I am using a YAML file for configuration in my rails app and a few entries in the file are subsets of future entries, eg -

> domain: domain.com 
>   name: jack 
>   email: jack@domain.com

To make this more efficient, is something like this possible in YAML ?

> domain: domain.com 
>   name: jack 
>   email: jack@${domain}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YAML has [anchors](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2785586), but you can't quite use them as variables the way you did in your question. You can get close with a post-processing step. Say your `domains.yaml` is

```
domains:
  - domain: &domain domain.com
    name: jack
    emaillocal: jack
    emaildomain: *domain

  - domain: &domain thehill.com
    name: Jill
    emaillocal: jill
    emaildomain: *domain
```

Then with

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby

require "yaml"

yaml = YAML.load_file('domains.yaml')

yaml['domains'].each { |d|
  d['email'] = d['emaillocal'] + '@' + d['emaildomain']
}

puts YAML::dump(yaml)
```

you get

```
domains: 
- name: jack
  emaildomain: domain.com
  domain: domain.com
  emaillocal: jack
  email: jack@domain.com
- name: Jill
  emaildomain: thehill.com
  domain: thehill.com
  emaillocal: jill
  email: jill@thehill.com
```

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.lathi.net/articles/2006/03/02/config-database-yml-goodness-for-teams might help